# How to transpose a dataframe in tidyverse?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, transpose

Using  basic R, I can transpose a dataframe, say `mtcars`, which has all columns of the same class:

```
as.data.frame(t(mtcars))
```

Or with pipes:

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>% t %>% as.data.frame
```

How to accomplish the same within tidyr or tidyverse packages?

My attempt below gives:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% gather(var, value, everything()) %>% spread(var, value)
```

Comment: If you want to transpose it it should be a matrix and not a data.frame. What's wrong with using `t`?

Comment: Try `add_rownames(mtcars) %>% gather(var, value, -rowname) %>% spread(rowname, value)`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You cannot meaningfully transpose a data.frame that contains many variable classes without loss of information.

Comment: A data frame, such as mtcars, might have all columns of the same class.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try with `add_rownames`

```
add_rownames(mtcars) %>% 
         gather(var, value, -rowname) %>% 
         spread(rowname, value)
```

In the newer version, `rownames_to_column` replaces `add_rownames`

```
mtcars %>%
   rownames_to_column %>% 
   gather(var, value, -rowname) %>% 
   spread(rowname, value)
```

In the even newer version, `pivot_wider` replaces `spread`:

```
mtcars %>%
   tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%  
   pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from=rowname, values_from=value)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Looks like add_rownames is depreciated, but this works:  mtcars %>% rownames_to_column %>% gather(var, value, -rowname) %>% spread(rowname, value)

Comment: Rows in the transformed data are by default ordered (alphabetically the mtcars case).
If you want to order the rows according to the initial column order (i.e. `names(mtcars)`) an additional step is required: `mtcars.t[order(match(mtcars.t$var,names(mtcars))),]`, where mtcars.t is the transformed data.

Comment: just after i hit submit i realized that `gather()` is now `pivot_longer()` :/

Comment: Puuh, that's pretty code intense as compared to ```t()```. Seems like something on the to do list for the next dplyr version.

Answer (score 11):

There's now a purpose-built function to do this, `rotate_df()` from `sjmisc`.

```
library(sjmisc)
mtcars %>% rotate_df()

#     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout Valiant Duster 360
#mpg      21.00        21.000      22.80         21.400             18.70   18.10      14.30
#cyl       6.00         6.000       4.00          6.000              8.00    6.00       8.00
#disp    160.00       160.000     108.00        258.000            360.00  225.00     360.00
#hp      110.00       110.000      93.00        110.000            175.00  105.00     245.00
#drat      3.90         3.900       3.85          3.080              3.15    2.76       3.21

#etc
```

The function also allows you to convert rownames to real df data with the rotate. Many thanks to the package creators.