# reshape untidy data frame, spreading rows to columns names

Tags: r, reshape2

Have searched the threads but can't understand a solution that will solve the problem with the data frame that I have.

My current data frame (df):

```
# A tibble: 8 x 29
  `Athlete`       Monday...2 Tuesday...3 Wednesday...4 Thursday...5 Friday...6 Saturday...7 Sunday...8
  <chr>           <chr>      <chr>       <chr>         <chr>        <chr>      <chr>        <chr>     
1 Date            29/06/2020 30/06/2020  43837.0       43868.0      43897.0    43928.0      43958.0   
2 HR              47.0       54.0        51.0          56.0         59.0       NA           NA        
3 HRV             171.0      91.0        127.0         99.0         77.0       NA           NA        
4 Sleep Duration  9.11       7.12        8.59          7.15         8.32       NA           NA        
5 Sleep Efficien~ 92.0       94.0        89.0          90.0         90.0       NA           NA        
6 Recovery Score  98.0       66.0        96.0          72.0         46.0       NA           NA        
7 Life Stress     NO         NO          NO            NO           NO         NA           NA        
8 Sick            NO         NO          NO            NO           NO         NA           NA
```

Have tried to use spread and pivot wider but I know there would require additional functions in order to get the desired output which beyond my level on understanding in R.

Do I need to u

Desired output:

```
 Date        HR       HRV      Sleep Duration   Sleep Efficiency   Recovery Score   Life Stress  Sick 
   29/06/2020    47.0      171.0       9.11
    30/06/2020   54.0      91.0        7.12
    43837.0      51.0      127.0       8.59
    43868.0      56.0      99.0        7.15
    43897.0      59.0      77.0        8.32
    43928.0       NA       NA           NA
    43958.0       NA       NA           NA
```

etc.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778908/transpose-a-data-frame or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306280/how-to-transpose-a-dataframe-in-tidyverse

Answer (score 0):

In Base R you will do:

```
type.convert(setNames(data.frame(t(df[-1]), row.names = NULL), df[,1]))

        Date HR HRV Sleep Duration Sleep Efficien~ Recovery Score Life Stress Sick
1 29/06/2020 47 171           9.11              92             98          NO   NO
2 30/06/2020 54  91           7.12              94             66          NO   NO
3    43837.0 51 127           8.59              89             96          NO   NO
4    43868.0 56  99           7.15              90             72          NO   NO
5    43897.0 59  77           8.32              90             46          NO   NO
6      43928 NA  NA             NA              NA             NA        <NA> <NA>
7      43958 NA  NA             NA              NA             NA        <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Works but the column headers are combined into one column  c("Date", "HR", "HRV", "Sleep Duration", "Sleep Efficiency", "Recovery Score", "Life Stress", "Sick")

Comment: @BigBird i see you are using a tibble. replace `df[,1]` in the code  above with `df[,1,drop = TRUE]`