# How to split bigrams into column and row pairs for n-columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

Supposing a dataframe like this:

```
# example dataset
df <- data.frame(
         rowid = 1:3,
         a = c("ax","cz","by"),
         b = c("cy","ax","bz"),
         c = c("bz","ay","cx")
      )
```

What would an efficient approach be to achieving the following transformation?

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>  rowid      a       b       c
#>  <int>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
#>      1      x       z       y
#>      2      x       y       z
#>      3      y       z       x
```

The goal is to take the second character of each bigram and sort it into columns picked-out by the first character, for each row.

If possible, it would be useful to compare base R and Tidyverse solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were looking for a comparison of base and Tidyverse, I'll chime in with a base solution:

```
tdf <- t(df[-1])
tdf[] <- substr(tdf, 2, 2)[order(col(tdf), tdf)]
df[-1] <- t(tdf)

#  rowid a b c
#1     1 x z y
#2     2 x y z
#3     3 y z x
```

To explain the 3 steps:

.1) take a copy of a `t()`ransposed version of the data
.2a) get the `order` within each row (`col()` now since it's transposed) of (implicitly the first letter of) each string
.2b) use this order to select from the second letter of each string and overwrite `<-` the transposed data.
.3) `t()`ranspose back to the original structure and overwrite `<-` the data in `df`

---

**Benchmark on 30K rows**

Base:

```
bigdf <- df[rep(1:3,10000),]
bigdf$rowid <- 1:30000

system.time({
    tdf <- t(bigdf[-1])
    tdf[] <- substr(tdf,2,2)[order(col(tdf), tdf)]
    bigdf[-1] <- t(tdf)
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.023   0.000   0.023
```

Tidy:

```
bigdf <- df[rep(1:3,10000),]
bigdf$rowid <- 1:30000

library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(sjmisc)
library(stringr)

system.time({
    bigdf %>%
        rotate_df(cn=TRUE) %>%
        mutate(across(everything(),sort)) %>%
        rotate_df() %>%
        mutate(across(everything(),~str_sub(.,2,-1))) %>%
        rownames_to_column(var="rowid")
})
##   user  system elapsed 
## 21.177   0.047  21.244
```

Comment: Elegant. Are there any strategies for this that don't use the transposition trick?

Comment: @louisdesu - there's probably several other ways to achieve this - reshaping to a long file, reordering, and reshaping back could do it too. But this was the quickest, least complicated way I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

A Tidyverse solution partially inspired by this recent post using `rotate_df()` from the `sjmisc` package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70682560/8068516

```
df <- data.frame(
     rowid = 1:3,
     a = c("ax","cz","by"),
     b = c("cy","ax","bz"),
     c = c("bz","ay","cx")
  )

library(sjmisc)
df %>%
  # transpose the dataframe keeping column names
  rotate_df(cn=TRUE) %>%
  # sort columns by first character
  mutate(across(everything(),sort)) %>%
  # transpose back
  rotate_df() %>%
  # remove first character from each string
  mutate(across(everything(),~str_sub(.,2,-1))) %>%
  # make `rowid` column
  rownames_to_column(var="rowid")
```

The dataframe can optionally be turned into tibble with `as_tibble()` to exactly match the target output, giving:

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>  rowid       a        b        c
#>  <int>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
#>      1       x        z        y
#>      2       x        y        z
#>      3       y        z        x
```

This solution will generalise to n-columns and is `%>%` compatible.